# Why I cannot show my MainWindow in PyQt5/PySide2?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pycharm, pyqt5, pyside2

I want to apply a round progress bar in my PyQt5/Pyside2 project. I've followed the Youtube tutorial and the function of the window worked, however when I tried to connect it in my MainWindow/Other Window. it gave me a 3 errors.

```
class introWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self) **// error in setupUi self.introWidget = QWidget(MainWindow)**

    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    #Buttons
    #Get Started Button
    self.ui.getstarted_btn.clicked.connect(self.callGetStart)
    self.show()

def callGetStart(self):
    self.hide()
    self.ui = home_Page()
```

Here's the code that I followed;

```
class progressWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_SplashScreen()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    ## ==> SET INITIAL PROGRESS BAR TO (0) ZERO
    self.progressBarValue(25)

    ## ==> REMOVE STANDARD TITLE BAR
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # Remove title bar
    self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)  # Set background to transparent

    ## ==> APPLY DROP SHADOW EFFECT
    self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
    self.shadow.setBlurRadius(20)
    self.shadow.setXOffset(0)
    self.shadow.setYOffset(0)
    self.shadow.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 120))
    self.ui.circularBg.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)

    ## QTIMER ==> START
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.progress)
    # TIMER IN MILLISECONDS
    self.timer.start(10)

    ## SHOW ==> MAIN WINDOW
    ########################################################################
    self.show()
    ## ==> END ##

# DEF TO LOADING
#######################################################################
def progress (self):
    global counter
    value = counter

    # SET VALUE TO PROGRESS BAR
    # fix max value error if > than 100
    if value >= 100: value = 1.000
    self.progressBarValue(value)

    # CLOSE SPLASH SCREE AND OPEN APP
    if counter > 100:
        # STOP TIMER
        self.timer.stop()

        # # # SHOW MAIN WINDOW
        self.ui = introWindow() **//error in progress self.ui = introWindow()**
        self.ui.show()


        # CLOSE SPLASH SCREEN
        self.close()

    # INCREASE COUNTER
    counter += 0.5

def progressBarValue(self, value):

    # PROGRESSBAR STYLESHEET BASE
    styleSheet = """
    QFrame{
        border-radius: 150px;
        background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:90, stop:{STOP_1} rgba(255, 0, 127, 0), stop:{STOP_2} rgba(85, 170, 255, 255));
    }
    """

    # GET PROGRESS BAR VALUE, CONVERT TO FLOAT AND INVERT VALUES
    # stop works of 1.000 to 0.000
    progress = (100 - value) / 100.0

    # GET NEW VALUES
    stop_1 = str(progress - 0.001)
    stop_2 = str(progress)

    # SET VALUES TO NEW STYLESHEET
    newStylesheet = styleSheet.replace("{STOP_1}", stop_1).replace("{STOP_2}", stop_2)

    # APPLY STYLESHEET WITH NEW VALUES
    self.ui.circularProgress.setStyleSheet(newStylesheet)
```

The last error is something I don't quitly understand it suddenly have an error on my GUI's.py and don't know how's that happen.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    if not MainWindow.objectName():
        MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1026, 741)
    self.introWidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.introWidget.setObjectName(u"introWidget")// **error in setupUi self.introWidget = QWidget(MainWindow)**
    self.getstarted_btn = QPushButton(self.introWidget)
    self.getstarted_btn.setObjectName(u"getstarted_btn")
    self.getstarted_btn.setGeometry(QRect(430, 380, 191, 71))
    self.getstarted_btn.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton{\n"
```

My terminal showed me an error;
TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'introWindow'

I tried many different ways to solve this problem, but Until now I still don't resolve.
Thank you seniors for helping overcome this thing.

Comment: please fix the indentation on your code  The error means you are sending the wrong data type to the QWidget constructor.  Try not passing it any arguments.

Comment: hello @alexpdev thank you for the respone, which of the 3 classes that I need to modify the indention?

Comment: @WreckitJeck "my PyQt5/Pyside2 project". It is either PyQt ***or*** PySide. You cannot use them both at the same time.

Comment: @musicamante thank you, its ok now. I used PyQt5 in my working environment, while the file I copied used Pyside2. Thank you sir/mam.